# How to always allow "[program] wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this."

Tags: macos, security, permission

I use a program which prompts me often to "make changes" (make a system-level/root-level change). I trust this program and want to always allow it to do so. How is this done? I would expect an "always allow" button, but there isn't one.

I know the system directory which the program wants to modify and that I could lower the permissions of that folder; however, that may have an impact on other applications which expect certain permissions on that folder, so I don't want to do that.

Here is an example of the dialog. (I removed the name for privacy.)
[image]

Comment: I would be very nervous about giving any app that sort of access to those areas of the file system. Not because the program could be hacked but that it may crash and in the process corrupt the whole directory. The chance of accidental damage is too high for my personal liking

Comment: I am a long-time python programmer and sysadmin, but not as familiar with OSX. In this specific case, the app is simple; it runs `pip install [package]` which modifies `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. If I don't trust `pip` (I do trust it), then I'm not going to get much accomplished. In some cases I will use `virtualenv`s which would not require root privileges, but that is too python-specific, and I have my reasoning for not using them here. I am looking for a general answer.

Comment: In general, my argument is this: I know what apps I trust (as far as malware and stability) and what apps I don't. OSX doesn't; only a human can make that determination. To this reasoning (I assume), OSX lets the **user** allow an app to make changes on a single-time basis in the case that the user does not fully trust an app. However, it does not have an implementation (that I can find) which represents the user's decision to give more trust to one app compared to another. If I don't fully trust an app, I would not even install it on my machine. I feel I don't need sandboxing most of the time

Comment: I recall seing something to make an executable always run as root, and without requiring permission. That could help for apps that only do root stuff. For others, running as root when not needed or intended might not be a good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow program to make changes](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122574/allow-program-to-make-changes)

Answer (score 2):

This is too large a trust you want to give to `osascript`.

Do you want this command to run without asking you for a real confirmation:

```
sudo osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to quit'
```

?